Which sound do you omit when pronouncing “asked” in “She asked me”?
When pronouncing the word “asked” in 'She asked me,' which consonant sound do you usually omit because it's too difficult for me to pronounce all four sounds (s+k+t+m)?

In UK people often say "arst" i.e. they omit the 'k'.

Why do you assume (or claim anyway) that omitting one of the consonants is an option? I mean, @WeatherVane has shown that some native speakers do omit one, but your phrasing suggests high confidence that nobody was going to answer, “None. All three must be pronounced.”

I don't omit the 'k' myself, although I barely pronounce it. It's very soft.

Shouldn't the 'all four sounds' be (s+k+ d +m)?

Oops, @MichaelHarvey, my degree in math never taught me to count (or to read closely).

Nothing is actually "dropped", but AAVE increasingly inverts the /s/ + /k/ sequence, so their version sounds like She axed me [a question]. You might consider that, even if you don't want to emulate AAVE in general. You'll always be understood, obviously. But as @PaulTanenbaum initially commented, it's common in relaxed BrE speech to discard the /k/ phoneme and reduce /d/ to something more like /t/ - which is easier to hear in She ahhst us [to do it].
